# Point new domain at subfolder of existing domains hosting?

Tags: web, hosting, dns

I have an existing domain which has some hosting, I recently purchased a new domain which is for a seperate site. Is it possible to host my new site in a subfolder on the existing hosting? I know you can use web forwarding but doesn't that have negative SEO implications?

Comment: Seems more suitable for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) or [superuser](http://superuser.com) - not sure which.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to set up an additional domain on your hosting, and it is usually labelled "Addon Domains" in your control panel.

Comment: Ok thanks, I couldn't see anything about addon domains, im with 123-reg, I have emailed them to ask.